# How to convert a stat output to a unix permissions string

Tags: python

If you run `os.stat(path)` on a file and then take its `st_mode` parameter, how do you get from there to a string like this: `rw-r--r--` as known from the Unix world?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Python 3.3 you could use [`stat.filemode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.filemode):

```
In [7]: import os, stat

In [8]: print(stat.filemode(os.stat('/home/soon/foo').st_mode))
-rw-r--r--

In [9]: ls -l ~/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 soon users 0 Jul 23 18:15 /home/soon/foo
```

Comment: +1 It can work in other python versions as well, simply copy the function and related data from the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/stat.py). Demo : http://ideone.com/P45ChT

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
import stat, os
def permissions_to_unix_name(st):
    is_dir = 'd' if stat.S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) else '-'
    dic = {'7':'rwx', '6' :'rw-', '5' : 'r-x', '4':'r--', '0': '---'}
    perm = str(oct(st.st_mode)[-3:])
    return is_dir + ''.join(dic.get(x,x) for x in perm)
... 

>>> permissions_to_unix_name(os.stat('.'))
'drwxr-xr-x'
>>> ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 62 monty monty 4096 Jul 23 13:23 ./

>>> permissions_to_unix_name(os.stat('so.py'))
'-rw-rw-r--'
>>> ls -ld so.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 monty monty 68 Jul 18 15:57 so.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function will achieve this, given some usual circumstances (i.e. I haven't tested it under Windows or with SELinux).

```
import stat
def permissions_to_unix_name(st_mode):
    permstr = ''
    usertypes = ['USR', 'GRP', 'OTH']
    for usertype in usertypes:
        perm_types = ['R', 'W', 'X']
        for permtype in perm_types:
            perm = getattr(stat, 'S_I%s%s' % (permtype, usertype))
            if st_mode & perm:
                permstr += permtype.lower()
            else:
                permstr += '-'
    return permstr
```

This produces a basic string as asked. However, this could also be improved to display further data, e.g. whether it is a directory (`d`) or a symlink (`l`). Feel free to improve it.